# How to use jQuery Ajax to submit a form to implement the form data to another cs file in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

How can implement a form to submit form data to another CS file. for updating the database. 
`Here is the form and the coding`

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="./update.aspx" class="col-md-10"  >


    <asp:Table ID="GridView1" class="nav-justified" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="628px" Width="763px">
        <asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4> Car name:</h4>

           </asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="newid" runat="server"  ReadOnly="true" Width="50px"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="carmake" runat="server" Width="301px"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

           </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4> Car model:</h4>
           </asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="carmodel" runat="server"   Width="301px" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4> Price: </h4>
           </asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="price"  runat="server" Width="301px"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4> Discounted Price If: </h4>
           </asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="d_price"  runat="server" Width="301px"  CssClass="form-control"/>
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell> <h4>Car image (Type url)</h4></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="image"   runat="server" />Just Location
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell><h4>Avilability</h4></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="avail"  runat="server" />Just Location
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell><h4>Quantity</h4></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="quantity"   runat="server" />Just Location
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4>Long description </h4>
           </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TextBox ID="details" runat="server" Width="295px"  CssClass="form-control" Height="81px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4>Year </h4>
           </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="year"  runat="server" Width="295px"  CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell>
                <h4>Special Discounted(0 0r 1) </h4>
           </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="special"  runat="server" Width="295px"  CssClass="form-control"  ></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table><asp:Button ID="button"  runat="server"  Cssclass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" Text="Update the car" />


<br />
   <br />

   </form>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form1").submit(
      function()
      {
        $.ajax
        ({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: "update.aspx/AcceptFormData",
             data: "{'funcParam':'"+$('#form1').serialize()+"'}",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(msg)
             {
                 var msgFromASPXFunction = msg.d
                 alert(data);
             }
         });
      }
     );
    });
</script> -->
```

here is the cs code

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class AdminGroup_Update : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constor = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constor);
         var id = Request.QueryString["newid"];
         var carmake = Request.QueryString["carmake"];
         var carmodel = Request.QueryString["carmodel"];
         var price = Request.QueryString["price"];
         var d_price = Request.QueryString["d_price"];
         var image = Request.QueryString["image"];
         var quantity = Request.QueryString["qnty"];
         var avail = Request.QueryString["avlb"];
         var details = Request.QueryString["details"];
         var year = Request.QueryString["year"];
         var special = Request.QueryString["special"]; 

        //var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        string sql = "Update product SET  car_make=@carmake, car_model=@carmodel, UnitPrice=@price, Discountprice=@d_price, image=@image, Quantity=@quantity, availability=@avail, details=@details, year=@year, special=@special   WHERE id= @id";
 var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
        {


conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            var ex = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (ex == 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("AdminList.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Error");
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
    }
```

those are the coding i just want a post the form data to another page where it should able to get all the data and update the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have ajax code to trigger the request

```
$.ajax
    ({
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url: "update.aspx/AcceptFormData",
         data: "{'funcParam':'"+$('#form1').serialize()+"'}",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(msg)
         {
             var msgFromASPXFunction = msg.d
             alert(data);
         }
     });

Create a new method in AcceptFormData in the class - AdminGroup_Update and modify the url in the javascript 
    from url: "update.aspx/AcceptFormData",
    to url: "AdminGroup_Update/AcceptFormData",

Make sure to check the input you are passing from the JQuery and the Inputs received at the server side(AdminGroup_Update class and AcceptFormData method)
```

Comment: Please add this code at the server side                                           public partial class AdminGroup_Update : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 }
 
 [WebMethod]
    public string AcceptFormData(your input)
    {
 
 }
}